How to set the position vtk vtkBillboardTextActor3D with vtkAssembly ? SetPosition is not working is not working
I would like to set the position of a vtkBillboardTextActor3D in a vtkassembly but the SetPosition is not working
    textActor = vtk.vtkBillboardTextActor3D()
    textActor.SetInput('Name') 
    textActor.SetPosition(0, 25, 0)
    textActor.GetTextProperty().SetFontSize(20)
    textActor.GetTextProperty().SetJustificationToCentered()

I also try this way :
    textTransform = vtk.vtkTransform()
    textOrigin = np.array([0.0, 50.0, 0.0])
    textPosition = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
    textTransform.TransformPoint(textOrigin, textPosition)
    print(textPosition)
    textActor.SetPosition(textPosition)

But both do not work. I get the text at the position 0,0,0

I don't understand what am  I doing wrong?
if I place every element in the renderer with
    for c in cylActors:
        self.ren.AddActor(c)

I get the correct answer

Here is the complete code :
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
import numpy as np

class Cylinder(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Cylinder, self).__init__( )

        self.parent=parent
        self.frame = QFrame()

        self.vl = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self.frame)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.vtkWidget)

        self.ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
        self.ren.SetBackground(.2, .3, .3)
        self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren = self.vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()
        style =vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera( )
        style.SetDefaultRenderer(self.ren)
        self.iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)
        self.ren.ResetCamera()
        self.frame.setLayout(self.vl)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.show()
        self.iren.Initialize()
        self.iren.Start()

        self.draw_Electrode()

    def set_center(self):
        self.ren.ResetCamera()

    def Render(self, ):
        self.iren.GetRenderWindow().Render()

    def draw_Electrode(self):
        cylActors = []
        textActor = vtk.vtkBillboardTextActor3D()
        textActor.SetInput('Name')
        # textTransform = vtk.vtkTransform()
        # textOrigin = np.array([0.0, 50.0, 0.0])
        # textPosition = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
        # textTransform.TransformPoint(textOrigin, textPosition)
        # print(textPosition)
        # textActor.SetPosition(textPosition)

        textActor.SetPosition(0, 25, 0)
        textActor.GetTextProperty().SetFontSize(20)
        textActor.GetTextProperty().SetJustificationToCentered()

        # textActor = vtk.vtkTextActor()
        # textActor.SetInput(self.Name)
        # textActor.SetCenter(0, -500, 0)
        cylActors.append(textActor)

        # design tube holding electrodes
        tube = vtk.vtkCylinderSource()
        tube.SetHeight(50)
        tube.SetCenter(0, 25, 0)
        tube.SetRadius(1)
        tubePoly = tube.GetOutput()
        # tubePoly.Update()
        tube.Update()
        TubeMT = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        TubeMT.SetInputData(tubePoly)
        TubeMT.Update()
        # TubeMT.GlobalImmediateModeRenderingOn()
        TubeA = vtk.vtkLODActor()
        TubeA.VisibilityOn()
        TubeA.SetMapper(TubeMT)
        TubeA.GetProperty().SetColor(1, 0, 0)
        cylActors.append(TubeA)


        self.Electrode_aAssemblys = []

        actAssembly = vtk.vtkAssembly()
        for c in cylActors:
            actAssembly.AddPart(c)
        self.Electrode_aAssemblys.append(actAssembly)
        self.ren.AddActor(self.Electrode_aAssemblys[-1])

 
        self.set_center()
        self.Render()



def main():
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)


    ex = Cylinder(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('Cylinder')
    # ex.showMaximized()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

